# Convert the fractional nonlinear optimisation problem to LP

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given an nonlinear optimisation problem of maximising (or minimising) $\frac{A(x,y)}{B(x,y)}$ where both $A(x,y)>0$ and $B(x,y)>0$, is it equivalent to maximise (minimise) $A(x,y)-B(x,y)$?

If no, how to convert this fractional NLP to LP in general?

Specifically, in my case, the $A(x,y)$ has a term $e^xy$, while $B(x,y)$ is a linear function of $x$ and $y$.